# uart issue in pi-3

Tags: pi-3, uart

I have a problem regarding the uart not working at all,
following are the steps as done from my side.

1. updated and upgraded the raspberry pi,initially i installed raspbian wheezy to sd card and i am running pi over ssh.
2. in config.txt added

   ```
   enable_uart=1
   core_freq=250
   force_turbo=1
   dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
   ```
3. in cmdline.txt removed the line related to ttyAMA0, the remaining command is as follows:

   ```
   dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait
   ```
4. i opened the minicom and tried to see if data appears, but i was not able to visualise any kind of data.
   Following is the python code:

   ```
   import time
   import serial
   print "Starting program"
   ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', baudrate=9600,
                       parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                       stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                       bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
                       )
   time.sleep(1)
   while 1:
       ser.write('Success')
       print 'Data Echo Mode Enabled'
       ser.close()
   ```

Comment: Why wheezy?  The better choice is the current jessie unless you actually need wheezy.  You appear to be following old instructions re the serial link in the Pi3.

Comment: i tried jessie too but still no success

Comment: i am using 9600 baudrate

Comment: @DipeshSharma Use "/dev/ttyS0" instead of "/dev/ttyAMA0"...

Comment: @fusseldieb : Sorry, but i am new to raspberry pi so i exactly dnt have idea how to use /dev/ttyS0

Comment: @DipeshSharma Just delete the "/dev/ttyAMA0" and write "/dev/ttyS0". Simple as that...

Comment: @Fusseldieb If Dipesh is using the `pi3-disable-bt` overlay then `ttyAMA0` is fine.

Comment: and when i run sudo systemctl disable hciuart to stop running bluetooth i am getting "system command not found"

Comment: @fusseldieb:- Thanks the /dev/ttyS0 solved the issue, but one thing i didnt understand i am able to see data on hercules(virtual terminal for usb to ttl ) but i was not able to visualise data on minicom

Comment: @DipeshSharma Even using "ttyS0"? Maybe wrong baudrate, stopbit, etc...? Or even switched TX RX pins... Or wrong TTL voltage (Unlikely, but not impossible)

Comment: @DipeshSharma `sudo systemctl disable hciuart` will only work on Jessie. 
 If you're using Wheezy, do something like `sudo update-rc.d hciuart disable`.

Comment: Might need to use `sudo minicom` in order to read from `/dev/ttyS0`.

Comment: @Fusseldieb,: The issue regarding the uart is solved. Thanks a lot guys for the support. The issue was with wire jumper connecting. Now i am able to see the data on minicom too.

Answer (score 1):

As detailed in the comments, the solution is to replace `"/dev/ttyAMA0"` with `"/dev/ttyS0"` in the code, giving:

```
import time
import serial
print "Starting program"
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0', baudrate=9600,
                    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
                    )
time.sleep(1)
while 1:
    ser.write('Success')
    print 'Data Echo Mode Enabled'
    ser.close()
```